# uibutton in collectionview cell action duplicating

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uibutton

So basically my problem is that when I click on a `button` which is present in collection view cell it should change the colour of button background colour. but the problem is it is changing the colour of another button. eg if I click on button 1 it changes the colour of button 6 automatically.

```
class hello: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!

    @IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {

        if btn.isSelected == true
        {
            btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            btn.isSelected = false
        }
        else{ btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
            btn.isSelected = true
        }
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }
}
          view controller file
```

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
     {

```
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "happy", for: indexPath) as! hello

    if cell.btn.isSelected
    {
        cell.btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                }
    else{ cell.btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple

    }

    cell.btn.tag = indexPath.item
    print(cell.btn.isSelected ,indexPath.row)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `btn` replace it with `sender` and change sender type `Any` to `UIButton` and check.

Comment: @AlishaChaudhary can you post the code conforming `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocol?

Comment: it is still not working. on pressing one button two buttons are being pressed.(0-5),(1-6),(2,7),(3-8),(4-9)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the UICollectionView re-uses cell for optimized scroll performance. Hence it re-uses the cell at index 1 when displaying cell at index 6 for e.g. Therefore you need to set the state of the cell when ever it is updated/reused.

The following function is called everytime. So you need to set cell.btn. backgroundColor over here.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     ...
     ...
     if dataSource[indexPath.row].selected {
       btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red 
     }else {
       btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
     }

     ...
     return cell
}
```

Now, it is upto your individual implementation, how you want to update the model when selection is changed. One option is you can define a protocol and implement it in your ViewController to update the values.